# Word 2010 VBA miscounts words per sentence against itself

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-count

The macro below is supposed to pull the average words per sentence, then turn the text red in all sentences that are >=150% of that.

The problem is, it turns *some* shorter sentences red, as well. For example, it colored these sentences (edited to add: in the source doc, 150% of average length is 35 words):

31 words: The FSAIPs provide the basis for evaluation of the adequacy of the regulatory implementation of the design based on this assumed operational process and supports the preparation of prospective dose assessments.

29 words: (In accordance with 10 CFR 835.2, the equivalent dose rate criteria are applicable at 30 cm from the radiation source or 30 cm from any surface the radiation penetrates.)

(I'd share more examples, but this is a radiation control procedure on a Federal nuclear project, so I'm having to choose carefully.)

Those word counts for the sentences above are from the status bar at the bottom of the window. So Word appears to be counting the number of words differently depending on what part of Word is counting. I think.

Are there any suggestions on how to make the count more accurate, or at least the same for both situations?  Oh, and a final note: it's not counting visible deleted words. It may be counting things like nonbreaking hyphens in some instances, but not in the ones shared above.

```
Sub Mark_Long()

'''''''''''''''''''
' Adapted from "Allen Wyatt's Word Tips, wordribbon.tips.net.
' I added to it so it pulls the avg sentence length from
' the readability stats, and only marks the sentences that are 150%
' of the average.
''''''''''''''''''''

Dim iMyCount As Integer
Dim iWords As Integer
Dim bTrackingAsWas As Boolean

    If Not ActiveDocument.Saved Then
        ActiveDocument.Save
    End If


Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    wordval = myRange.ReadabilityStatistics(6).Value
    bTrackingAsWas = ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions

    'Turn off tracked changes
    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False

    'Reset counter
    iMyCount = 0

    'Set number of words
    iWords = (wordval * 1.5)

    For Each MySent In ActiveDocument.Sentences
        If MySent.Words.Count > iWords Then
            MySent.Font.Color = wdColorRed
            iMyCount = iMyCount + 1
        End If
    Next
    'Restore tracked changes
    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = bTrackingAsWas

    'Report results
    MsgBox iMyCount & " sentences longer than " & _
      iWords & " words."

End Sub
```

Comment: I just spent some time trying to recreate his issue. It is true that there is a difference in the VBA word count vs the Word Count in the Word GUI. Most of the time its adding a word but ive seem some cases of it being off by almost 5. Havent found an explanation as of yet

Answer (score 1):

you should use .Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords) instead of .Words.Count.
The first returns a filtered value, the second an unfiltered

See:
http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-21723.html

Comment: More specific link [Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291447/word-count-appears-inaccurate-when-you-use-the-vba-words-property). **Note:** this ```ComputeStatistics``` takes quite a while on large documents, even if you just want to have a word count for a specific paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

The property `.Words` returns real words but also punctuation marks and paragraph marks. To get the real word count you can use this - a little bit weird - method.

```
Set dlg = Dialogs(wdDialogToolsWordCount)
For Each MySent In ActiveDocument.Sentences
    MySent.Select
    Set dlg = Dialogs(wdDialogToolsWordCount)
    dlg.Execute
    Count = dlg.Words
    ' Count is the number you are looking for
Next
```

You just simulate the 'Word Count' dialog.

Comment: I'm SO sorry this withered for three weeks. Customer priorities kept me from working on this. @Fratyx, I tried adding `MsgBox Count` before `Next`, and your method gives an accurate count for each sentence -- although at the very beginning and end of a doc, I get the total word count for the file (and tables are very slow). With `MsgBox Count` at the end of the Sub, I only get the word count of the last sentence. It's like I need to average all of the results. If there isn't a mostly easy way to do it, I'll just bump up the multiplier in my original code and call that close enough. Thanks.